# Start event B after A is done

Tags: c#

I have quit button with really simple function *close();*.

How can i do that? After sound end (2-3sec) app close.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Play sound
this.playSound();

// WAIT FOR END OF SOUND

Close();
}

private void playSound()
{
            Random random = new Random();

            // Create list of quit music
            List<System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream> sound = new List<System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream>
            {
                global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_1,
                global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_2,
                global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_3,
                global::Launcher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_4,
            };

            // Random, set and play sound
            (new SoundPlayer(sound[random.Next(sound.Count)])).Play();
}
```

Comment: Don't wait in GUI event handlers.  What is playSound() and what events/methods are exposed by it?

Comment: playSound() is function for play sound. I think that is simple!

Comment: Depends on what playSound does. Synchronous methods will block until complete. If playSound is asynchronous there will be some system of notification that the call is complete. Research C# asynchronous patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application will close because the sound you are playing was played in a different thread than the main User Interface thread. You can always change `(new SoundPlayer(sound[random.Next(sound.Count)])).Play();` to `(new SoundPlayer(sound[random.Next(sound.Count)])).PlaySync();` if you'd like to play the sound using the user interface (UI) thread. So that the application  would wait for the `SoundPlayer` to stop playing the Wave Sound file then closes the `Form`

**Example**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Play sound
    this.playSound();

    // WAIT FOR END OF SOUND

    Close();
}
private void playSound()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    // Create list of quit music
    List<System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream> sound = new List<System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream>
    {
        global::StrongholdCrusaderLauncher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_1,
        global::StrongholdCrusaderLauncher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_2,
        global::StrongholdCrusaderLauncher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_3,
        global::StrongholdCrusaderLauncher.Properties.Resources.sound_quit_4,
    };

    // Random, set and play sound
    (new SoundPlayer(sound[random.Next(sound.Count)])).PlaySync(); //We've changed Play(); to PlaySync(); so that the Wave Sound file would be played in the main user interface thread
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If `playSound()` is synchronous you can try

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Play sound
  this.playSound();
  BackgroundWorker wk = new BackGroundWorker();
  wk.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) => {Thread.Sleep(2000); Close(); };
  wk.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This prevents GUI to seems locked as it could using simpler way

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Play sound
  this.playSound();
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  Close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(new SoundPlayer(sound[random.Next(sound.Count)])).Play();
```

This will play the sound asynchronously, so it happens on a separate thread. The downside is that there is no information about when the sound finishes.

What you can do instead is use [`PlaySync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx) manually on a separate thread and have a callback to your main thread which then closes the application.